# Making python press "enter" in order to confirm a print dialog

Tags: python, printing

I have a code which detects if there is a new file, and if there is one, print it. But print it in real life, in paper. My problem is that with some extensions, (.JPG ...) It asks for a confirmation like a print button. I need it to print autamic without any human intersection.
How can I make python to press the print button??
Or make the print button not appear at all??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module pyatuogui will help you, for print you can use

```
pyatuogui.typewrite (['ctrl','p'])
```

Or

```
pyatuogui.typewrite(['enter"])
```

Comment: thanks i pretty sure it works. It worked once but now i am getting some trouble

Comment: Then try doing this

Comment: ```  pyautogui.hotkey('enter')  ```  if that dosent works then it must be that your dialog box is not selected or you can add time delay for that.